# Angular Http Request .subscribe() cause an infinite loop

Tags: http, post, token, jwt, angular5

I want to write a function `loggedIn()` in file `auth.service.ts` to check the token from local storage, and then verify it with [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) in server side. But the code in Typescript gives an infinite loop. Here is my code:

auth.service.ts

```
loggedIn(){

    const token: string = localStorage.getItem('id_token');    

    if (token == null) {
      return false;
    }

    else {
      const subs = this.http.post('http://localhost/url/to/myPHP.php', {"token":token})
      .map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
        if(data.valid){
          this.valid = true;
        } else {
          this.valid = false;
        }
      },
    err=>console.log(err));

      if (this.valid){
        console.log("Valid");
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Given token: valid token.
Result: give no error but infinite console.log of 'Valid' as well as return true, until the Apache down.
Given token: invalid token
Result: give no error but infinite console.log of 'Invalid' as well as return false, until the Apache down.

What I have tried:

```
    loggedIn(){
        const token: string = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

        if (token == null) {
          return false;
        }

        else {
          const subs = this.http.post('http://localhost/url/to/myPHP.php', {"token":token})
          .map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
            if(data.valid){
              this.valid = true;
            } else {
              this.valid = false;
            }
          },
        err=>console.log(err));

          if (this.valid){
            console.log("Valid");
            console.log(this.valid);
            return true;
          } else {
            console.log("Invalid");
            console.log(this.valid);
            return false;
          }
          subs.unsubscribe();
          return true;
        }
      }
```

The line `subs.unsubscribe();` did stop the loop, yet it will literally unsubscribe the `Observable<Response>` and the code inside `.subscribe()` will not run. Please help.

**Edit**: Usage of `loggedIn()`

```
*ngIf="authService.loggedIn()
```

for 4 times in navbar component.

Inside `auth.guard.ts`

```
canActivate(){
        if (this.authService.validToken){
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In `app.module.ts` 
`{path:'profile', component:ProfileComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}`

Comment: Have you tracked how many times your `loggedIn()` method is being called? Have you used something like `ngIf="loggedIn()"` in your template which is being evaluated on every tick?

Comment: Yes I dd, It's being called for 5 times. including the 'ngIf'

Comment: Call it once in your `ngOnInit()`, set a local variable, and refer to the variable instead of the method in your template.

Comment: Depends on what the rest of your application looks like. Should be easy enough to trace though.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks for your advice, I'll try it out.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen `ngOnInit` in auth.service.ts doesn't run. :(

Comment: **NOTE**: This is a service class with `@Injectable()` , this is why `ngOnInit()` doesn't work. Besides, I have moved the logic to `constructor`, and it only runs once for each construction as expected. The expected result should be binding with the latest `loggedIn()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the problem. 
The **problem** with my code: `.subscribe()` is an async call (which actually scheduled for last/later execution). This is the situation:
**`ngOnInit()` :** which located in component < ts > file

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.authService.loggedIn();
    console.log("10");
  }
```

**`loggedIn()` :** which located in auth.service.ts file

```
  loggedIn(){

        const token: string = localStorage.getItem('id_token');    

        if (token == null) {
          return false;
        }

        else {
          const subs = this.http.post('http://localhost/url/to/myPHP.php', {"token":token})
          .map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
            if(data.valid){
              console.log("1");
            } else {
              console.log("2");
            }

            console.log("3")
          },
        err=>console.log(err));
        }
      }
```

and then the result will be :
10
1
3
 which mean, anything you do inside the subscribe will change only after you need it (in many cases). So we need to do whatever we need to, inside the `subscribe()`, and fire it only when needed. In my case, I want to fire it if any changes apply to token inside local storage.

**This is my solution**

As I want it always check with the token. I used `DoCheck()`

Inside `auth.service.ts`

```
verifyToken(authToken) {
    const body = {token:authToken};

    return this.http.post('http://localhost/url/to/myPHP.php',body)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }


tokenExist(): boolean {
    const token: string = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

    if (token == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Inside `navbar.component.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.curToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.loggedIn(this.curToken);
  }

  ngDoCheck(){
    if (this.curToken != localStorage.getItem('id_token')){
      this.curToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
      this.loggedIn(this.curToken);
    }
  }

  loggedIn(token){
    if(this.authService.tokenExist()){
      this.authService.verifyToken(token).subscribe(data=>{
        if(data.valid){
          this.validLogin = true;
        } else {
          console.log("Invalid Token");
          this.validLogin = false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Token Missing");
      this.validLogin = false;
    }

  }
```

Of course, don't forget to implement `DoCheck` in the line

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck
```